# Hibernate generating bad syntax sql

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

There are two tables: bb_players and bb_player_skills.
player skills table has one to one relation with bb_players, and also foreign key to bb_players.

Error happens at executing this code:

```
Query q = em.createNamedQuery(PlayerSkill.DELETE_SKILL_BY_PLAYER_ID);
q.setParameter("playerID", playerID);
q.executeUpdate();
```

The named query is:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = PlayerSkill.DELETE_SKILL_BY_PLAYER_ID, query = "DELETE FROM   PlayerSkill s " +
 " WHERE s.player.id = :playerID")
```

The error from postgresql logs is:

```
ERROR,42601,"syntax error at or near ""cross""",,,,,, 
 "delete from bb_player_skills cross join bb_players player1_ where id=$1",30,,""
```

Is my named query wrong and how should I rewrite it?

Comment: Why do you need a named query for a simple delete by PK?

Comment: @torvin what do you suggest, pure sql ?

Comment: I suggest pure Hibernate: use proper mapping for your Player class and use `session.delete()` to delete it. And Hibernate would create the query by itself without your help.

Comment: @torvin can you please provide simple example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that this may be an open Hibernate issue depending on your Hibernate version.

From: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7314

> Using a JPA Delete query with conditions requiring a join through Hibernate entity-manager generates invalid SQL for PostgreSQL.
>   PostgreSQL cannot use CROSS JOIN in the FROM clause of a DELETE query.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else faces the same problem,Here is one solution.
The named query can be rewritten to avoid join cross.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "PlayerSkill.DELETE_SKILL_BY_PLAYER_ID", query = "DELETE FROM   PlayerSkill s " +
 " WHERE s.player IN (SELECT player FROM Player player where player.id=:playerID)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not a one to one relation. From bb_players it shoutd be a one to many relation, from bb_player_skills it should be a many to one relation.